# I Want to Read .word format Document body and To display the content of body in VF Page as a String

Tags: salesforce, apex

I Have uploaded a .word file in Document Object.Now I want to get that content(body) of that file and I want to dislay whole content in Visual Force Page.

```
Document doc = [Select d.body from Document d where d.name='docname';
Blob b = doc.body;
String Str = b.toString();

//This Giving an Error Encoding UTC8.

//Then Modified to like below but it's not giving correct data.
//It's giving like    @5ywnnn7*96w**.

Document doc = [Select d.body from Document d where d.name='docname';
Blob b = doc.body;
String Str = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(b);
```

Thanks In Advance.